# Unable to create new React Native app with Expo

Tags: npm, expo

I attempted to create a new React native project using the expo-cli. I enter the command "npx create-expo-app my-app" and I get this message in the terminal "Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank@latest --dry-run""

And the error it gives me is "Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0".

This has come completely out of nowhere. I had created a new expo project just yesterday with no issues. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the expo-cli and updated node and npm.

The versions I am using are:

npm  - 8.13.2 |
node - 16.15.1 |
expo-cli - 5.4.12

If anyone knows why this might be happening, I'd appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Hi Max did you find out what went wrong with this, i have exact same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with the version of node of your machine.

Try:
`nvm use --lts`. Maybe you need to install it before `nvm install --lts`.

For intalling nvm with a quick search you can get it.